# Не работают команды элемента после перезагрузки грида. MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Всем доброго времени!

Проект WPF, MVVM, есть DataGrid заполненный коллекцией элементов.
Через DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate сделана выплывающая панель с кнопками, привязанных к командам выбранного элемента.

В момент ручного выбора строки и нажатия кнопки на раскрывшейся панели проблем не возникает.
Но если же после обновления списка элементов выбрать программно элемент (через OnPropertyChanged("SelectedElem")), то кнопки работают только через даблклик. Создается ощущение, что команды не привязываются в первый раз, тк во время отладки после первого клика по кнопке не вызывается команда.

View

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementsCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid  Visibility="{Binding IsCanAnyAction, Converter={StaticResource IsEnabledToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <StackPanel>                            
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" IsThreeState="False" 
                                        Command="{Binding ViewCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Focusable="True"
                                        Visibility="{Binding IsCanView, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource IsEnabledToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <ToggleButton.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="..."/>
                                <Label Content="Просмотреть" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToggleButton.Content>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" IsThreeState="False" 
                                        Command="{Binding ChangeCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Focusable="True"
                                        Visibility="{Binding IsCanChange, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource IsEnabledToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <ToggleButton.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="..."/>
                                <Label Content="Редактировать"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToggleButton.Content>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="False" IsThreeState="False"
                                        Command="{Binding CompleteCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Focusable="True"
                                        Visibility="{Binding IsCanComplete, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource IsEnabledToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <ToggleButton.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="..."/>
                                <Image Source="..."/>
                                <Label Content="Зафиксировать"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToggleButton.Content>
                    </ToggleButton>                         
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

ElementsCollection представляет собой ObservableCollection во ViewModel

Model

```
public class MyElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private RelayCommand _viewCommand;
        private RelayCommand _changeCommand;
        private RelayCommand _completeCommand;

        public bool IsEditable { get; set; }

        public ICommand ViewCommand
        {
            get { return _viewCommand ?? (_viewCommand = new RelayCommand(param => View(), param => CanView())); }
        }

        public ICommand ChangeCommand
        {
            get { return _changeCommand ?? (_changeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Change(), param => CanChange())); }
        }

        public ICommand CompleteCommand
        {
            get { return _completeCommand ?? (_completeCommand = new RelayCommand(param => Complete(), param => CanComplete())); }
        }

        <...>
    }
```

Команда

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly Action<object> execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

P.S. .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: Если заменить `ToggleButton` на обычный `Button` результат будет тем-же?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да, ситуация не меняется

Comment: Если добавите [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) будет проще разобраться

Comment: А что означает «выбрать программно элемент через `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedElem")`»? Выглядит очень подозрительно.